Quarkus SmallRye JWT GCP Identity Aware Proxy (IAP) integration
I am trying to figure out, how Quarkus SmallRye JWT (https://quarkus.io/guides/security-jwt) could work together with GCP's Identity Aware Proxy (https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/signed-headers-howto?hl=de#securing_iap_headers).
The GCP Loadbalancer forwards the JWT in the header x-goog-iap-jwt-assertion.
How could I configure SmallRye JWT to pick up the right header without the 'Bearer' scheme and to use the public key provided here https://www.gstatic.com/iap/verify/public_key?
I tried something like
mp.jwt.verify.publickey=MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE43cTT9GWJlLTzgB...
quarkus.smallrye-jwt.enabled=true
mp.jwt.token.header=x-goog-iap-jwt-assertion

but I always get back
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< www-authenticate: Bearer
< content-length: 0


The following worked:
mp.jwt.verify.publickey.location=https://www.gstatic.com/iap/verify/public_key-jwk
mp.jwt.verify.publickey.algorithm=ES256
mp.jwt.verify.issuer=https://cloud.google.com/iap
mp.jwt.verify.audiences=/projects/xxxxx/global/backendServices/xxxxxx
mp.jwt.token.header=x-goog-iap-jwt-assertion

Notice algorithm=ES256

Can you try this:
mp.jwt.verify.publickey.location=https://www.gstatic.com/iap/verify/public_key
mp.jwt.verify.issuer=my-issuer
mp.jwt.verify.audiences=my-audience
mp.jwt.token.header=x-goog-iap-jwt-assertion

Note the issuer and optionally the audience.

This leads to
Caused by: org.jose4j.lang.UnresolvableKeyException: SRJWT07005: Failed to load a key from https://www.gstatic.com/iap/verify/public_key property while resolving
at io.smallrye.jwt.auth.principal.AbstractKeyLocationResolver.reportUnresolvableKeyException(AbstractKeyLocationResolver.java:227)
at io.smallrye.jwt.auth.principal.KeyLocationResolver.resolveKey(KeyLocationResolver.java:76)
